# Check if string is a glob pattern

Tags: ruby, glob

On the input I have string that can be plain path string (e.g. `/home/user/1.txt`) or glob pattern (e.g. `/home/user/*.txt`).

Next I want to get array of matches if string is glob pattern and in case when string is just plain path I want to get array with single element - this path.

So somehow I should check if string contains unescaped glob symbols and if it does then call `Pathname.glob()` to get matches otherwise just return array with this string.

How can I check if string is a glob pattern?

**UPDATE**

I had this question while implementing [homebrew cask glob pattern support for zap stanza](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/2042).
And the solution that I used is to made a little refactoring to avoid need to check if string is a glob pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Next I want to get array of matches if string is glob pattern and in case when string is just plain path I want to get array with single element - this path.*

They're both valid glob patterns. One contains a wildcard, one does not. Run them both through `Pathname.glob()` and you'll always get an array back. Bonus, it'll check if it matches anything.

```
$ irb
2.3.3 :001 > require "pathname"
 => true 
2.3.3 :002 > Pathname.glob("test.data")
 => [#<Pathname:test.data>] 
2.3.3 :003 > Pathname.glob("test.*")
 => [#<Pathname:test.asm>, #<Pathname:test.c>, #<Pathname:test.cpp>, #<Pathname:test.csv>, #<Pathname:test.data>, #<Pathname:test.dSYM>, #<Pathname:test.html>, #<Pathname:test.out>, #<Pathname:test.php>, #<Pathname:test.pl>, #<Pathname:test.py>, #<Pathname:test.rb>, #<Pathname:test.s>, #<Pathname:test.sh>] 
2.3.3 :004 > Pathname.glob("doesnotexist")
 => []
```

This is a great way to normalize and validate your data early, so the rest of the program doesn't have to.

---

If you *really* want to figure out if something is a literal path or a glob, you *could* try scanning for any special glob characters, but that rapidly gets complicated and error prone. It requires [knowing how `glob` works in detail](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and remembering to check for quoting and escaping. `foo*` has a glob pattern. `foo\*` does not. `foo[123]` does. `foo\[123]` does not. And I'm not sure what `foo[123\]` is doing, I think it counts as a non-terminated set.

In general, you want to avoid writing code that has to reproduce the inner workings of another piece of code. If there was a `Pathname.has_glob_chars` you could use that, but there isn't such a thing.

`Pathname.glob` uses [`File.fnmatch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) to do the globbing and you can use that without touching the filesystem. You might be able to come up with something using that, but I can't make it work. I thought maybe only a literal path will match itself, but `foo*` defeats that.

Instead, check if it exists.

```
Pathname.new(path).exist?
```

If it exists, it was a real path to a real file. If it didn't exist, it might have been a real path, or it might be a glob. That's probably good enough.

You can also check by looking to see if `Pathname.glob(path)` returned a single element that matches the original path. Note that when matching paths it's important to normalize both sides with `cleanpath`.

```
paths = Pathname.glob(path)

if paths.size == 1 && paths[0].cleanpath == Pathname.new(path).cleanpath
    puts "#{path} is a literal path"
elsif paths.size == 0
    puts "#{path} matched nothing"
else
    puts "#{path} was a glob"
end
```

Comment: Yes, plain path is also valid glob pattern (let's call it trivial). But a glob pattern is not a valid path. I want to know when I deal with non-trivial pattern and when with plain path.

Comment: @mixel Why? You wanted to reduce the path/glob down to a list of paths. `Pathname.glob` does that. Figuring out if it's a literal path just adds code and time and complexity and bugs.

Comment: I know that but it will take a long time to explain why I need this so I hoped that there is some standard way to check if string is non-trivial glob pattern it in Ruby. If there is no simple way except regex matching then ok, I will try to figure it out or may be even refactor my project to eliminate the need to check.

Comment: @mixel You have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there's probably a better way to solve it. You should ask about the real problem you're trying to solve, even if it's hard to explain, in a new question. It will be harder to maintain code that tries to determine if a path contains globs.

Comment: Refactoring seems like the best solution. You shouldn't have to check to see whether the glob is trivial or complex, your code should just work in either case.